# Calculate a new field containing X and Y coordinates

Tags: field-calculator, coordinates

I am using QGIS 3.22. I wish to add a field that will represent X,Y or Lat Lon values
I managed to create a field for X (using $X) and a field for Y (using $Y) but how do I combine them to one field like this:
177852,655321

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need a `string` type field, and you need to use pipes (`||`), like

`$x||','||$y`

`$x` and `$y` you already know, and the pipes concatenate characters. The output could be an integer value, or you can chime in a comma (`','`) in between to get the notation you want.

Answer (score 2):

A widely used alternative is:

```
Concat ($x, ',', $y)
```

concat : https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#concat